# Generating a table from object array

Tags: reactjs, html-table

If I have a state like so:

```js
 state = {
    Data: [
      {
          inputArr: [1, 2, 3],

      },
      {
         inputArr: [1, 2, 3],

      },
      {
          inputArr: [1, 2, 3],

      }
    ]
  };
```

and I want to make a table from the input Arr so that I will have 3 rows 3 cols and it will be in order, 123,123,123

I thought about double map but it doesn't work, is there a better way?

```js
const test=this.state.data.map( (val)=>{
   val.map( (val2)=>{
 <tr>
    return (
  <th> val2 </th>
      )
    }
 </tr>
}
```

Comment: That should actually work fine. You're just not returning anything from your first `map` though, also `val2` should be between curly brackets. Let me know if that works.

Comment: the <tr> above the return is giving me a syntax error..

Comment: and if I remove the tr it sais val is not a function

Comment: You had to access `val.inputArr` instead of `val`, and also the opening of the `tr` tag should be outside the map. Try this: https://codesandbox.io/embed/q8zl5p9x5q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a nested map and return JSX elements from both of them

```
const test= this.state.Data.map((val, index)=>{
     return (
        <tr key={index}>
           {val.inputArr.map((val2)=>{
                return (
                  <th key={val2}>{val2}</th>
                )
            })}
        </tr>
     )
}
```

You also need to provide a key for the elements

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Data: [
      {
          inputArr: [1, 2, 3],

      },
      {
         inputArr: [1, 2, 3],

      },
      {
          inputArr: [1, 2, 3],

      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const test= this.state.Data.map((val, index)=>{
         return (
            <tr key={index}>
               {val.inputArr.map((val2)=>{
                    return (
                      <th key={val2}>{val2}</th>
                    )
                })}
            </tr>
         )
    })
    return <div>{test}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: this does not compile.

Comment: "," expected and the field goes red, you know compilation error

Answer (score 1):

I see you already accepted an answer but I would like to elaborate on what was wrong with your code.

```
render() {
  const test=this.state.Data.map((val, index1)=>(
    <tr key={index1}>
      {val.inputArr.map( (val2, index2) => <td key={index2}>{val2}</td> )}
    </tr>
  ))

  return <table>{test}</table>;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hp6nj3qt/)

- JavaScript is case sensitive, your property is `Data` not `data`.
- Take care using the correct `{}` or `()` with arrow functions. Using `{}` means you can make multiple statements and explicitly return something. Using `()` will automatically return the expression.
- To output a value in React wrap it in `{}` like I did with `{val2}`
- Given your data structure, you must use the `inputarr` propety when accessing the inner array.
- Use a `key` on element lists. You can [read about keys in react here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: thank you for your contribution, you cleared some things for me